# How to fix error with Keras Flatten layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

This is my  code

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1,11)),    
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),   
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')  
]
)
```

My data is 1000 rows with 11 columns (11 inputs for the model). So to make the input layer of the NN I used flatten. This gives me the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 11) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 11), dtype=tf.float32, name='flatten_1_input'), name='flatten_1_input', description="created by layer 'flatten_1_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 11).
```

Comment: to solve the issue more of your code (the input part especially) needed. Also, this looks like a dimension as the error points, hence print the shape of your input to make sure it is the one you think.

Comment: Use `Keras.layers.Input()` instead of `Keras.layers.Flatten()`.

Comment: I tried  keras.layers.Input(input_shape=(1,11)) but it gives me an error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your input shape is `(num_inputs, 11)` already so you don't need to flatten it. Taking out the `Flatten` layer should fix this.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! If I take out the line would this remove the input layer of my NN? Or how would I replace this line with a line to define my input layer?

Comment: I haven't used keras in a long time, but if I recall correctly you would have to add `input_shape=(11)` to the new first layer (`keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(11))`)

Comment: Oops seems I was wrong, you would have to change the first layer to `keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu', input_dim=11)`

Comment: If this solves your question, feel free to mark it as correct. Glad I could help!